# How to avoid campaign goes to spam filter?

Tags: mailchimp, campaign-monitor

When  I am using the text 'zaamor' and send a campaign it goes to inbox.

and if I using `'zaamor.com'` it goes to `spam filters`.

If I using the `'zaamor.in'` it goes to `inbox`.

Actually 'zaamor.com' is my working site. More times we have sent campaigns. But this time only it goes to 'spam' folder. I have checked 'gmail' and 'yahoo' mail for testing.  I have used sendy and mail chimp.

Comment: Well, the obvious answer would be - stop sending mail that looks like spam. Then it'll stop getting filtered.

Comment: Its very urgent to send users. When I am using `.com'` it makes a problem. Any other ways to avoid it  ?